# Cocoa: Loop through all controls in a window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, controls

I am programming Mac apps with Cocoa.

How can I loop over/enumerate all the buttons, labels and other GUI controls in a NSWindow? I want to get the labels of each control

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you'd want something like:

```
- (void)addLabelsFromSubviewsOf:(NSView *)view to:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    // get the label from this view, if it has one;
    // I'm unsure what test you want here, maybe:
    if([view respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)])
        [array addObject:[view stringValue]];

    // or possibly:
    //    if([view isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]) ?

    // and traverse all subviews
    for(NSView *view in [view subviews])
    {
        [self addLabelsFromSubviewsOf:view to:array];
    }
}

...

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[self addLabelsFromSubviewsOf:[window contentView] to:array];
```

Views can have subviews, so it ends up being a tree walk. In this code I've just used simple recursion to achieve that.

Comment: Hi Tommy, thanks, your solution looks fine. When I try that on a NSWindow's contentView, its subviews are actually empty, I cannot get access to the NSButtons on it. Will you help? Thanks

Comment: That's really odd. If you NSLog the contentView do you get something appropriate?

Comment: The output is <NSView: 0x339790>

Comment: Does the tick mean you solved your problem? I'm otherwise intending to put together a little test tomorrow, to try to figure out what might be going on.

Comment: Tommy, the recursion solution works. Finally, inspired by your solution, I wrote a non-recursive algorithm, and put all the NSView into a NSMutableArray, and then loop through each control and determine its class. Thanks